# utf8::all on perl-5.12.3 doesn't work and I can't uninstall it

Tags: perl, utf-8, module

On Mac OS X 10.7.5 on which `perl-5.12.3` is installed, I needed to use the `utf8::all` module so I have manually installed [utf8-all-0.024](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8::all) (Note the minimum perl version of `v5.10.0` on its CPAN page) The `make test` has failed but I've still installed it to see if it would work. It didn't work so I've decided to uninstall it. I've tried 2 methods given at [perl.com](https://www.perl.com/article/3/2013/3/27/How-to-cleanly-uninstall-a-Perl-module) the first method didn't work as it required `perl-5.14.2` The second method gave this message:

```
! utf-8 is not found in the following directories and can't be uninstalled.

  /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
  /Library/Perl/5.12
```

and it couldn't uninstall it either. How to uninstall the `utf8-all-0.024`?

Furthermore, I had a small script listing all the Perl modules. It is:

```perl
use ExtUtils::Installed;
my $inst = ExtUtils::Installed->new();
my @modules = $inst->modules();
foreach $module (@modules) {
    print $module . "\n";
}
```

This script started to take about a minute and half of the CPU time, to list the modules. Before I messed up the system, it was giving instant result. How to rectify it?

For the sake of completeness here is the `@INC` as given by the `perl -V`

```sh
  @INC:
    /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.12
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.12
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3
    /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.12
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12
    .
```

Further info:

`perl -Mutf8::all -e 'print $INC{"utf8/all.pm"}, "\n"'` gives:

```
Can't locate Import/Into.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library
/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library
/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-
thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library
/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library
/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /Library/Perl/5.12/utf8/all.pm line 140.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Library/Perl/5.12/utf8/all.pm line 140.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Comment: What is the output of `perl -Mutf8::all -e 'print $INC{"utf8/all.pm"}, "\n"'` ?

Comment: The output is several lines long enough not to fit in here so I'll add it in the topic in a minute.

Comment: Seems like you got an incomplete installation of `utf8::all` since one of its dependent modules `Import::Into` is not installed. Maybe you could try install that module, and see if `utf8::all` then works better? Try run `cpan Import::Into`

Comment: *"/Library/Perl/5.12/utf8/all.pm line 140."* This shows that the module is installed at `/Library/Perl/5.12/utf8/all.pm`

Comment: Quick comment: `sudo cpanm Import::Intro` gave: ! Finding Import::Intro on cpanmetadb failed.
! Finding Import::Intro () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Import::Intro

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled that. It should be `Into` not `Intro`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you for the comment. I've just found the cause. After I've entered `cpan utf8::all`, I've noticed that cpan was outputting lines starting with `/Users/Matt/.cpan/` and failed. But the `/Users/Matt/`directory no longer existed on this Mac because I had changed it about 2 years ago to some other name but I've totally forgotten about it so that didn't even cross my mind until I've seen it printed on the Terminal. Now I've modified all occurrences of `Matt` in the `.cpan` folder and did the `cpan` with the `-t` and `f` options as given in the answer below and finally it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a mess of things by incorrectly installing the module. Specifically, you didn't install the dependencies.

Ideally, you should use the package manager that provided `perl` itself. But they don't provide every module. So you'd use the non-package manager approach:

```sh
cpan utf8::all
```

(I prefer to install my own `perl` using `perlbrew`, then I can use `cpan` without worry.)

Now, `cpan` might claim that utf8::all is already installed. If so, this should get you straightened out:

```sh
cpan -t utf8::all
cpan -f utf8::all   # Only if the previous command says everything is ok!
```

Comment: After I've tried the `cpan utf8::all` I've noticed cpan was outputting lines  with `/Users/Matt/.cpan/` and it failed. But the `/Users/Matt/` directory no longer existed on this Mac because I had changed it to some other name about 2 years ago i.e. before the covid thing, so I've completely forgotten about this change and it didn't even cross my mind until I've seen them printed on the screen. After I've modified all occurrences of Matt in the `~/.cpan` folder and did the `cpan` again and with the -t and f options,  did utf8 finally get installed and my CGI script using `utf8` started working.

Comment: (Could have deleted ~/.cpan)

Comment: yep but because the then running Perl (as a FCGI process) didn't cause any trouble at the time, so I didn't do any deletion or anything.